# Modifying the host file in C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc when creating IIS website

Tags: powershell, iis

I am trying to create my website through powershell by using the following command

```
New-Website -Name 'mytestapp' -force -Port 8080 -HostHeader mytestsite -PhysicalPath 'C:\Users\myuser\Desktop\Docker\PublishOutput' -ApplicationPool '.NET v4.5'
```

I also set the hostheader and indeed I can see in IIS the relative binding. Unfortunately when I navigate to the website nothing happens, because in the **host** file in C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc there is no mapping between 127.0.0.1 and *mytestsite* , which I would expect to happen from the creation of the site itself. How do I do this in a smart way through powershell? I don't want a command to modify a text file, I would expect there is some powershell command IIS related that does this for me.

Comment: `echo "127.0.0.1 mytestsite" >> "$env:windir\system32\drivers\etc\hosts"`?

Comment: I am confused by the false constraint that you are putting on yourself? **"I don't want a command to modify a text file"**. If there were some already existing powershell cmdlet to do this what do you think it would do? The hosts file is simply a text file.

Comment: @EBGreen isn't there any "set-binding"-like command that does it for me? I would expect the "new-website" command to do it for me for example.. because even if there is the binding on iis but then I cannot resolve it on the host, how can it be useful? maybe I am missing some part of the story :)

Comment: A production system should modify DNS (what PowerShell of course natively supports), instead of hosts file. So your statement "which I would expect to happen from the creation of the site itself" is not really a valid one.